# Cant find queries in Sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm working with a site and using Access 2007-2010 & Sharepoint 2010.
The thing is that in Access I can see all my tables, queries, forms, reports and macros, but when I open the site in Sharepoint I can only see the tables.

I need to delete a query and create a new one and sync it over to Sharepoint, but the problem is that I cant see the query in Sharepoint so I cant delete it.
Even if I delete the query in Access & and sync it to Sharepoint it will not sync/remove the query from Sharepoint.

I also tried to delete the query in Access, create a new query with same name and sync it, then it will get the same name but appends with my name on it.

1. How can I see all the queries, forms and so on in Sharepoint?
2. How can I delete a query in Sharepoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the application to SharePoint, or did you “up-size” using the database tools tab?

If you published as a web based, then your application is “flagged” (converted) to a web based application. And this occurs even if your application has NO web objects at all! You can tell this “flipping” since the ribbon features change to creating web objects by default:
You see this:

[image]

However, if you just push up the tables, then you see the regular ribbon. This would suggest you used the database tools tab on the ribbon. This feature allows you to export data to say SQL server or in this case SharePoint tables. When you do this, NONE of the objects like forms, query etc. are saved on SharePoint. You will ONLY see the tables and only have table links.

If you did web publish, then while viewing the web site, you should be able to go choose from the options drop down in the web heading area – choose “settings” and you thus should see all saved objects of your database, including queries.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. We think this is web-base publish because of the globes we also have.

NOW. How can I remove a specific Query from Sharepoint if I cant see it? I mean, I created a new query "abc-query" and this query is somewhere in Sharepoint, because when we sync, our query will get the name "abc-query1"